# How to generate missing secret_key_base specific to particular environment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-6

While trying to start unicorn server for a particular environment I'm getting following error:

```
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.4/gems/railties-6.0.6/lib/rails/application.rb:588:in `validate_secret_key_base': Missing `secret_key_base` for 'bm_demo_app' environment, set this string with `rails credentials:edit` (ArgumentError)
```

I tried creating secret key using following command:

```
ubuntu@ip-172-31-44-32:/var/www/vyrill$ RAILS_ENV=bm_demo_app rake secret
5d171b5b9650e29eb6bedb67fec4b937e09f3a255c2b0bdb035232089e8c70356b19ec715a5cc5816220992b23eb566854451c42d44f9c6d03b2ceb17d748d41
ubuntu@ip-172-31-44-32:/var/www/vyrill$
```

I then tried creating master.key & environment specific key file as follows:

```
ubuntu@ip-172-31-44-32:/var/www/vyrill$ EDITOR="mate --wait" bin/rails credentials:edit
Adding config/master.key to store the encryption key: 5b0aead14ad12307d07ee057a3750149

Save this in a password manager your team can access.

If you lose the key, no one, including you, can access anything encrypted with it.

      create  config/master.key

Couldn't decrypt config/credentials.yml.enc. Perhaps you passed the wrong key?
ubuntu@ip-172-31-44-32:/var/www/vyrill$
```

```
ubuntu@ip-172-31-44-32:/var/www/vyrill$ EDITOR="nano" bin/rails credentials:edit --environment=bm_demo_app
Adding config/credentials/bm_demo_app.key to store the encryption key: 876e7225eefe68c0eb3e8a75f648a6f6

Save this in a password manager your team can access.

If you lose the key, no one, including you, can access anything encrypted with it.

      create  config/credentials/bm_demo_app.key

Ignoring config/credentials/bm_demo_app.key so it won't end up in Git history:

      append  .gitignore

File encrypted and saved.
ubuntu@ip-172-31-44-32:/var/www/vyrill$
```

But still while starting unicorn I continue to get `Missing secret_key_base for bm_demo_app environment, set this string with rails credentials:edit (ArgumentError)` error.

Comment: `create  config/master.key` -- where is your original `master.key`?

Comment: @mechnicov this is a new project & as you can check `EDITOR="mate --wait" bin/rails credentials:edit` command created config/master.key

Comment: No. This key is generated in new app automatically after `rails new` command

Comment: @mechnicov somehow locally this file was neither present nor required & I had to manually generate it after deployment on AWS EC2 instance